# Capture/Record windows sound

Tags: c#, c++, windows, multimedia

I need to record the sounds on windows. I need to write to stream what I hear from speakers.
What means/API can I rely on?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to make use of [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318665%28VS.85%29.aspx); a sample can be found [here](http://khason.net/blog/capturing-and-streaming-sound-by-using-directsound-with-c/) which is working against a mic. The [CaptureDevicesCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb280815%28VS.85%29.aspx) should have a reference to the needed device you want to capture audio from to change from a mic to something else.

Comment: To set it up to record what you hear from speakers, look at this link: http://cow.neondragon.net/index.php/2141-Recording-Sound-Output-In-Windows